# Android Collision of two Imageviews

Tags: android, collision

I am new to Android and wanted to create a game in which i have two, moving Players at the bottom of the screen and non-stop spawning objects at the top of the screen, moving downwards.(Like the App '2Cars' from Ketchapp.

Here is the problem : I want to check the collision between the falling objects and the movable objects. How can I achieve this. (I was searching for almost 3 days and didnt found an answer)

```
public class GameAcvitiy extends Activity {
protected ImageView mMoverr;
protected ImageView mMoverl;
private int count = 0;
private int countr = 0;
private int leftm = 0;
private int rightm = 0;
public int y;
public int x;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_acvitiy);
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(GameAcvitiy.this,R.raw.drums);
    mediaPlayer.start();
    mMoverl = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.charal);
    mMoverr = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.charar);

    // Hin und her bewegung
    Button l = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.changelanebuttonl);
    l.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            count++;
            if (count == 1) {
                mMoverl.animate().x(275).setDuration(200);
            }
            if (count == 2) {
                mMoverl.animate().x(0).setDuration(200);
                count--;
                count--;
            }
        }
    });

    Button r = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.changelanebuttonr);
    r.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            countr++;
            if (countr == 1) {
                mMoverr.animate().x(605).setDuration(200);
            }
            if (countr == 2) {
                mMoverr.animate().x(875).setDuration(200);
                countr--;
                countr--;
            }
        }
    });

    (new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            while (!Thread.interrupted())
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(1500);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {
                            spawn();

                        }
                    });
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    //error
                }
        }
    })).start();
}


public void spawn() {
    Random r = new Random();
    int spawnc = r.nextInt(3 - 1) + 1;

    if (spawnc == 1) {
        leftm = 0;
    }
    if (spawnc == 2) {
        leftm = 275;
    }

    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutBase);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.chara);
    lp.topMargin = 0;
    lp.leftMargin = leftm;
    rl.addView(iv, lp);
    iv.animate().y(1900).setDuration(4000);

    Random vrt = new Random();
    int spawnvt = vrt.nextInt(4 - 1) + 1;
    if (spawnvt == 1) {
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.charab);
    }
    if (spawnvt == 2) {
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.charag);
    }
    if (spawnvt == 3) {
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.charan);
    }


    //Spawn2
    Random rr = new Random();
    int spawnct = rr.nextInt(3 - 1) + 1;

    if (spawnct == 1) {
        rightm = 605;
    }
    if (spawnct == 2) {
        rightm = 875;
    }

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    ImageView ivt = new ImageView(this);
    ivt.setImageResource(R.drawable.chara);
    lp2.topMargin = 0;
    lp2.leftMargin = rightm;
    rl.addView(ivt, lp2);
    ivt.animate().y(1900).setDuration(4000);

    Random vr = new Random();
    int spawnv = vr.nextInt(4 - 1) + 1;

    if (spawnv == 1) {
        ivt.setImageResource(R.drawable.charab);
    }
    if (spawnv == 2) {
        ivt.setImageResource(R.drawable.charag);
    }
    if (spawnv == 3) {
        ivt.setImageResource(R.drawable.charan);
    }
        collide(mMoverr, ivt);
        collide(mMoverl, iv);
}


public void collide(ImageView firstIV, ImageView secondIV){
    Rect rc1 = new Rect();
    firstIV.getHitRect(rc1);
    Rect rc2 = new Rect();
    secondIV.getHitRect(rc2);

    if (Rect.intersects(rc1,rc2)) {
        Toast.makeText(GameAcvitiy.this, "BUM", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
    }
}
```

Thank you so far guys. I hope you can help me

Comment: Lets say that each character and object is represented by a single dot. To check for a collision, just check whether the coordinates of two objects are identical. Once you understand and can draw this on paper, you can come up with simple ways of checking whether two objects bounded by a box (or some other shape) intersect. If you've ever played the game battleship, the concept is the same.

Comment: At least comment in all that code where specifically you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

The getHitRect method is the correct one to be used, you can check pixel perfect collision by enabling pointer location in developer options and see the exact coordinates when your ImageViews moves.
Next time, put only relevant code and not all your code...